# a href no funciona en mi página html

Tags: html, css

Tengo un enlace que dirige al `checkout` de la página pero por alguna razón no se dirige al darle <kbd>click</kbd>, pero al darle <kbd>click</kbd> derecho abrir en nueva pestaña si sale.
¿Por qué pasa esto?

```
<div class="cartFooter clearfix">
   <div class="cartTotal">
     Total
     <span class="vtexsc-totalCart"><span class="vtexsc-text">$ 100,00</span>
   </div>
   <a href="/checkout/#/cart" class="cartCheckout"></a>
   <a href="https://www.google.com" class="" style="background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 100px;padding: 0 12px;"></a>
</div>
```

Agregue otra url sencilla de google y pasa lo mismo, muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: `<span class="vtexsc-totalCart"><span class="vtexsc-text">$ 100,00</span>` ¿Dónde cierras ese  `span`? sí no lo cierras puede ser una de las razones por la cual no funciona bien

Answer (score 2):

Las etiquetas están vacías y por lo tanto los enlaces no se mostrarán, cambia el código a algo como esto:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cartFooter clearfix">
   <div class="cartTotal">
 Total
 <span class="vtexsc-totalCart"><span class="vtexsc-text">$ 100,00</span>
   </div>
   <a href="/checkout/#/cart" class="cartCheckout">ir al CheckOut</a>
   <br>
   <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="" style="background-color: black; width: 100%; height: 100px;padding: 0 12px;">Ir a google</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Viendo todo lo anterior, entiendo que el enlace `<a href="/checkout/#/cart" class="cartCheckout"></a>` aparece ya que tendrá un estilo que lo hace visible, como un `display: block o inline-block;` con un cierto grosor, imagen de fondo, etc.

Se me ocurren dos posibles problemas derivado de que funcione al abrir una nueva pestaña:

- Que se deba a que al contener una almohadilla lo interprete el navegador como ancla si ya está en la página de `checkout` puesto que la dirección es absoluta al contener una `/` al principio e implica que si ya se encuentra en `/checkout/` sí o sí será interpretado así. (Lo cual si ocurre al cargar un enlace externo como google, como indicas, es extraño)
- Que el template de tienda que estés intentando modificar tenga un script que al hacer click haga un `prevent` del evento, por lo que deberías revisarlo.

Si es el primer caso, la solución es simple (pero cutre, recomendaría cambiar el comportamiento per se):

```
<a href="/checkout/#/cart" onclick="location = '/checkout/#/cart'; location.reload();" class="cartCheckout"></a>
```

Espero que esto sirva, un saludo

Answer (score 0):

No tiene nada entre el `<a href...>` y `</a>`  Por eso no hay nada para cliquear para seguir el enlace.  Por ejemplo:

```
<a href="/checkout/#/cart" class="cartCheckout">Va al Checkout</a>
```

Comment: Lo curioso es que dice que abriendo nueva pestaña funciona. :S

Comment: No creo que sea eso, ves que tiene un class, pues supongo que es para darle forma al botón, sino hubiese cometido el mismo error con el otro botón que hizo de prueba, pero a ese sí le dio forma, pues mi suposición

Answer (score 0):

Veo que abres dos `span`, pero solo cierras uno

```
<span class="vtexsc-totalCart"><span class="vtexsc-text">$ 100,00</span>
```

Sí no lo cierras puede ser una de las razones por la cual no funciona bien, por lo tanto debes cerra la etiqueta del `span` para que no haya inconsistencias a la hora de usar los elementos que coloques después.

Queda así:

```
<span class="vtexsc-totalCart"><span class="vtexsc-text">$ 100,00</span></span>
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos!!